# Scroll down over the Lightning Chart JS

Tags: lightningchart

I am testing Lightning Chart and I want to scroll down the website instead of zooming in the chart.

Example: https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-renderingSpeed/

If you look at this chart, I am able to scroll down only when I keep mouse over the title of chart. Instead, how to scroll down the webpage no matter where my mouse is?

Comment: On that page they are initializing div on element wtih width:100% and height:100%, meaning it take full body, for your case you could create smaller div and initialize chart there

Comment: yea , I mean even if the chart is small  , if i want to scroll down , I am unable to if my mouse is over the small div chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should work

```
chart.setMouseInteractionWheelZoom(false)
```

And it does work at least at their site when i'm adding it: https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0000-lineSeries.html